# Selecting Specific Data in an Data Frame to replace using the Row and Column names

Tags: r, select, na, .when

I am attempting to replace specific NA values with 0 in my data table. I do not want all NAs replaces, only those under certain conditions. For example, "replace NA with Zeros when the row is Cole_1 and the Column includes the designation 'Fall1'". I have a huge data set, so I need as little manual designating as possible, numbering each column is not an option. Basically, I want to be able to target the cells like playing battleship.

I have tried:

```r
whentest <- count_order_site %>% 
  when(select(contains("Fall1")) & 
  count_order_site[count_order_site$Point_Name == "Cole_1", ], 
  count_order_site[is.na(count_order_site)] <- 0 )
```

but get an error "`contains()` must be used within a *selecting* function."
I'm not even sure if this is the right path to get what I want.

The basic layout idea (Sorry it's stacked weird, I can't figure out how to make them next to each other):

| Point Name | ACWO_Fall1 |
| --- | --- |
| Cole_1 | NA |
| Cole_2 | 3 |

| ACWO_FAll2 | HOSP_FAll1 |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | NA |
| NA | 5 |

After the functions the data would look like:

| Point Name | ACWO_Fall1 |
| --- | --- |
| Cole_1 | 0 |
| Cole_2 | 3 |

| ACWO_FAll2 | HOSP_FAll1 |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 0 |
| NA | 5 |

Comment: Also, it helps to use numbers rather than "huge", which tends to just mean bigger than I'm used to.  E.g. do you mean millions of rows, trillions?

Comment: Yes it is R, thank you. The real data has 2,876 columns, so too big to make me want to go through manually, plus my PI would really rather a condensed code to do it. The three components do what I want individually, but I don't know how to string them together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use `mutate` `across` to include columns that contain certain character values, such as "Fall1". Then, with the `replace` function, replace those values that are missing using `is.na` and where the `point_name` has a specific value, such as "Cole_1".

The example below has a couple extra columns to demonstrate if the logic is correct.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(across(contains("Fall1"), ~replace(., is.na(.) & point_name == "Cole_1", 0)))
```

**Output**

```
  point_name ACWO_Fall1 ACWO_Fall2 HOSP_Fall1 Other1 Other_Fall1
1     Cole_1          0          3          0     NA           6
2     Cole_2          3         NA          5     NA          NA
```

Comment: This did exactly what I wanted! Thank you so much!